# Suggested Questions from Friedberg's Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm self-studying Friedberg's *Linear Algebra* and I was wondering whether anyone could direct me to a resource that gives recommended homework exercises.

Comment: Are you talking about [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-4th-Stephen-Friedberg/dp/0130084514)? Aren't there exercises in the book?

Comment: I mean a list of recommended, select exercises

Comment: When Terry Tao taught linear algebra at UCLA (back in 2002), this book was used. You may want to take a look at his [old course page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/). He has written a set of excellent lecture notes for the course.

Answer (score 0):

I found some under homework problems in the following link:

https://math.berkeley.edu/~nadler/110fall2012

The list is not crazy long, but I would imagine it is enough to get you started. The solutions are also posted.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to go through all of the exercises in the chapters 1 through 6 (except for those sections marked with a star) and then consider comparing them with solution manuals. Solution are available on the internet, for instance [here](https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link).

If you really can't solve them all, then the following exercises should give you a basic understanding about LA:

- Section 1.2: problems 6, 16, 21.
- Section 1.3: problems 8, 9, 19, 23, 29, 30.
- Section 1.4: problems 5, 15.
- Section 1.5: problems 3, 9, 11, 13.
- Section 1.6: problems 4, 9, 13, 17, 20, 26, 29, 34.
- Section 2.1: problems 6, 11, 12, 20, 22, 24, 35.
- Section 2.2: problems 2b, 6, 8, 12, 16.
- Section 2.3: problems 2, 12, 13.
- Section 2.4: problems 2, 3, 5, 6.
- Section 2.5: problems 2, 7.
- Section 2.6: problems 3, 9, 19, 20.
- Section 3.1: 12.
- Section 3.2: 3, 4, 5 (a), (b), (c), 6 (a), (b), (c), 7, 14, 17.
- Section 3.3: 2 (a), (b), 3 (a), (b), 8, 10.
- Section 3.4: 2 (a), (f), 12.
- Section 4.3: 15, 21.
- Section 5.1: 3 (a), 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 20.
- Section 5.2: 3 (f), 7, 12, 13, 18.
- Section 5.4: 3, 6 (a), 18, 19, 42.
- Section 6.1: 4 (a), 8 (a), 9, 11, 12.
- Section 6.2: 2 (b), 6, 13, 19 (b).
- Section 6.3: 2 (b), 7, 8, 12.
- Section 6.4: 2 (a), 3, 6, 9.
- Section 7.1: 1, 3 (a), 13.
- Section 7.2: 1, 4 (a), 5 (a), 6.
- Section 7.3: 1, 2 (d), 5.